# Downloading a static resource does not save with extension

Tags: static-resources

I have a csv file as a static resource and i am allowing users to download this file using the following.

```
<a href="{!URLFOR($Resource.AccountUploadTemplate)}" target="_blank">Click here </a>
```

[image]

The issue i face is that the download file does not have an extension and file type is File when viewed in windows explorer.

[image]

Is there anyway we can force it to save with an extension?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way that it is possible to force an extension on [Static Resources](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm) when downloading them. **However**, you can upload all Static Resources in a Zip File. That way you would know that there is only one extension type for all Static Resources.

Here's the Visualforce mark-up for including a file within a compressed (zipped) Static Resource.

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.Zip_File_Static_Resource, 'File_Within_Zip_File.js')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use download attribute in Anchor Tag

```
<a download="test.docx" href="{!$Resource.test}" target="_blank">Test Doc</a>
```